# What difference does it make writing code in fetch's success and collection object's bind event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Fetch's success and binds's sync can perform the same operations. Which is a good practice?

```
closure._allusers.fetch({  
            reset:true,  
            success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);  
                alert("Fetch successful");  
            }  
    });  
    closure._allusers.bind("sync", function(data) {  
        console.log(data.models[0].attributes.result);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First difference: `success` is called just before `sync` is triggered (can matter if you have to use both for some reason).
Second one, and the most important, they are quite different because one is a listener and the other an option you specify. Apart from being 2 ways of doing things, the listener has the advantage of giving you the opportunity to do something while not caring about the origin. Also, you only have to write it once.

Answer (score 0):

The model sync method is called by Backbone save method to formulate an ajax restful json request. The only time you can bind or override the sync method is when you have a different saving strategy, such as websockets, XML transport, or local storage.